# Is it possible to make a Laravel Eloquent Cast that returns a comma decimal in the echo and a dot decimal in the mathematical operation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, casting

I have a big problem! ;)

A have a database data with decimal values (1.1, 1.19, 2, ...)

I'm trying to make a Eloquent Cast Class that works on two different context:

1. Return a comma decimal when it's used on echo o print

> `echo $data->level;` //  1,10    1,19  2,00 ...
> it's already working

2. Make a operation like sum or multiplication

> `$sum = $data->level + $data->level;` //2.29

I've already reached this function below where it works with echo, but it gives the error **Unsupported operand types: App\Models\Casts\NumberFormat + App\Models\Casts\NumberFormat** when I try to do sums
<?php

```
namespace App\Models\Casts;
 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class NumberFormat implements CastsAttributes
{

    public $formated;

    public function get(Model $model, string $key, mixed $value, array $attributes)
    {
        $this->formated = number_format($value, 2, ',', '');
        return $this;

    }

    public function __toString(){

        return $this->formated;
    }
}
```

If i do get method like this:

```
public function get(Model $model, string $key, mixed $value, array $attributes)
{
   return $value;
}
```

So the __toStrings() doesn't get() called (because get() returns a string), sum works but echo prints 1.1 1.19 2 ...

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you explicitly mention, where do you perform the arithmetic operations?

Comment: $sum = 0;
foreach($datas as $data)
{
    $sum += $data->level; //  i wanted  1.18
    echo $data->level; //  i wanted  1,18
}
echo $sum;

Comment: i know it's possible cause when i use in model:
    protected $casts = [
        'date_update' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
];  
i get Illuminate\Support\Carbon on var_dump AND string on echo

Comment: That's because the Carbon object defines a `__toString()` method. Just create an accessor named e.g. `formattedLevel` that uses the custom cast and use it for display purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

The casts neither support nor call the `__toString` method, so what you can do is to return the formatted_value from the get method and when performing calculations, you can get the raw attribute via `getAttributes` method of eloquent models.

## NumberFormat.php

```php
  /**
   * Cast the given value.
   *
   * @param  array<string, mixed>  $attributes
   */
  public function get(Model $model, string $key, mixed $value, array $attributes): mixed
  {
    return number_format($value, 2);
  }
```

Now when you perform calculations it depends if you are doing inside the model, or elsewhere, but i am going to give you a general solution which is calling the `getAttributes` method of eloquent model as follow:

```php
$sum = $data->getAttributes()['level'] + $data->getAttributes()['level'];
```

Comment: I trying public function get(Model $model, string $key, mixed $value, array $attributes) { return number_format($value, 2, ',',''); } cause i need a latin like format comma decimal.
Interesting that  
if use $dado->getAttributes()['nivel'] produce 9.18, otherwise if use $dado->getAttribute('nivel') produce 9,18. I think this it is an inconsistency.

Comment: i want works like this: in model: protected $casts = [ 'date_update' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s', ]; So in view i get Illuminate\Support\Carbon on var_dump AND string on echo

Comment: I am not clear about your comments, what you want to deliver, because in one comment you mention about formatting the level and in other you mention the carbon. If possible update the post and provide exact scenario stepwise regarding what you want us to help you.

Comment: sorry for confuse. I mentioned Carbom like a example because I wanna the same behavior in my Cast. Ex: I wold like my NumberFormat Class comes out 1,20 when use with echo; and comes out Obect in var_dump(). If use $cast['level' => 'datetime']; its works this way